# Reverse an input using tuples Python

Tags: python

I want to be able to write  function that will reverse a phrase such as 'Hello World' into 'World Hello'. So far i can get to:

```
def reverser():
    print('Please input a phrase')
    inputphrase=input()
    if ' ' in inputphrase:
```

after this I'm assuming you need to slice the string and then that slice gets stored in a tuple, and at the end the variables will print out.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be stored in a `list`, not a `tuple`. Here's how you do it in 2 lines:

```
my_input = input('Your phrase: ')
print(*reversed(my_input.split()))  # Python 3
```

or

```
print ' '.join(reversed(a.split()))  # Python 2
```

So the function would be:

```
func = lambda x: reversed(x.split())
```

which will return a list of reversed words from the phrase if called as follows:

```
arg = input('Enter a phrase :')
splitted = func(arg)

print(*splitted)  # or in Python 2: print ' '.join(splitted)
```

Comment: Any ways on how to do it with tuple?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You cannot change them. Any manipulations must be stored in a separate variable (either as a tuple or a list) and used later. You can change it from a list to a tuple though: `my_tuple = tuple(reversed(x.split()))`. By the way, I implemented the function for you too. You can add `tuple()` to it, so that it returns a tuple.

Comment: If you mean how you can used `reversed` on tuples, it's the same. However, if you mean how you can use `split()` on a tuple, that you cannot. Split can only be implemented on a string. You can do this to split everything in your tuple though: `var = [item.split() for item in my_tuple]`

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as such so that the thread is closed and the question is removed from the board. Otherwise, go ahead and ask more! ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) built-in

```
def reverser():
    return ' '.join(reversed(input('Please input a phrase:').split()))
```

the input string is split on whitespace, then passed to reversed, then joined again

For example use it as

```
>>> print(reverser())
Please input a phrase:hello world how are you
you are how world hello
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> inputphrase = "Hello World"
>>> parts = inputphrase.split(' ')
>>> parts.reverse()
>>> ' '.join(parts)
'World Hello'
```

You don't need to test `if ' ' in inputphrase:` as `parts` will contain just a single item in that case.

It's a good idea to make your functions have a single purpose. You should have one function for getting the input, and another for reversing it.

Comment: `split()` doesn't require an input for space.

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri, it does it you want to split on exactly "just single spaces" Without a parameter it will split on any whitespace

Answer (score 0):

> Python programming language provides a neat syntax to reverse a
>   tuple.The syntax is `var[::-1]` which returns a reverse copy of the var.
>
> Example:

```
def reverser():
    inputphrase = tuple(x.strip() for x in raw_input("Please input a phrase: ").split(' '))
    return inputphrase[::-1]

print reverser()
```

> Output:

```
Please input a phrase: Hello World 
('World', 'Hello')
```

> Or you can do it this way.

```
def reverser():
            inputphrase = tuple(x.strip() for x in raw_input("Please input a phrase: ").split(' '))
            return tuple(reversed(inputphrase))

print reverser()
```

> Output:

```
Please input a phrase: Hello World. 
('World.', 'Hello')
```